# xpath is giving a node with null value

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I am using XPath for the first time. While I am trying to get a node from xml I am getting a node with null value.

here is the xml file look like..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Message>
<Header>
<FromCompany>Content</FromCompany>
<From>Source</From>
<FromEmail>eg@eg.com</FromEmail>
<Toy>Pocket</Toy>
<SentDate>20300709</SentDate>
</Header>
```

...

I have written xpath expr as below ...

```
public XPath xPath =  XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
Node message = (Node) xPath.evaluate("/Message", pxml, XPathConstants.NODE);
System.out.println("message::" + message);
```

When I execute message node is not null but is printing data as 
message::[Message: null]

I am not able to get the content of the node.. Could some one help me to find what I have done wrong?

Comment: where is `_message` defined?

Comment: "_" is a mistake in editing.. it is message only.

Answer (score 2):

In this context xPath will return a [`org.w3c.dom.Node`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html), which is expected (I hope).

To get the contents of the node, you need to use `Node#getTextContent`, which, using your example, outputs...

```
Content
Source
eg@eg.com
Pocket
20300709
```

Comment: Thanks it got resolved by using getTextContent instead of getNodeValue.